# XAMPP wont open simplest route with laravel, if it is not a home route

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, laravel, xampp, laravel-routing

So I am having huge problems with XAMPP today ( I don't know why, never had them before ).

It gives me the "route not found exception" when I want to access any other route than the basic home `"/"` route.
On the other hand, if I use `artisan serve` and visit the exact same route in my browser, everything works as expected.

I tried googling this for the whole afternoon today, losing my mind already! Tried reinstalling XAMPP, tried making sure `mod_rewrite` is enabled etc. Everything is ok, it still wont work!

Can anyone **please** help with this issue? Here are the images

**Route file**

[image]

**XAMPP browser**

[image]

**Artisan browser**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Check your VirtualHost, you probably have .htaccess files disabled (AllowOverride is not set to All).

Comment: Hi :) Ty for answering. I forgot to mention that I have also made all AllowOverride lines in my xampp conf file equal to All

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, the problem kinda fixed itself, and I still have no idea how... I reinstalled XAMPP the second time and it worked out of the box...

Sometimes, I swear... it seems like development is just screwing with your head on purpose.